Integration of Synxis with C# Webview and Sebre APIs
I'm currently working on integrating SynXis with a C# webview to streamline the process of pushing values from an ID scanner into fields such as first name, last name, and address. Additionally, I'm interested in retrieving data post-reservation, such as confirmation numbers and stay dates. Initially, I attempted to achieve this directly on the website but encountered a cross-origin iframe issue. Subsequently, I discovered that Sebre offers a comprehensive set of APIs. However, I'm uncertain which specific APIs would enable me to accomplish these tasks. My overarching objective is to scan an ID, extract the data, and seamlessly inject it into SynXis to enhance the efficiency of front desk operations.
I need a method to allow me to inject and get data from a SynXis site.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
